# Water world in gazebo for surface vehicle

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to create water world in gazebo. i tried to use buoyancy plugin and drag plugin for it. But the buoyancy plugin acts for the entire world. i want buoyancy till certain level of water. How can this task be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23674/water-world-in-gazebo-for-surface-vehicle/) by [uchiha_saail](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14015/uchiha_saail/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can take a look at the VRX project, where Gazebo is used to simulate a maritime environment. There is a buoyancy plugin that takes into account the level of the water.

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/vrx

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2019-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uchiha_saail](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14015/uchiha_saail/) on 2019-09-05**:
I have gone through the vrx plugin, but i just want simple buoyancy plugin up to level of still water with drag force of water acting on water.